# Algorithm stops illogically?

Tags: coordinates

I have been stuck on this problem for about 2 days now. Today after a lot of debugging I figured out that my nearest neighbour algorithm doesn't finish completely and stops in between when the last element from the ArrayList is removed.

I have 2 arrayLists
One contains the X coordinates of all the cities and the other one contains the Y coordinates of all the cities.
I am using a for loop to calculate the distances between the cities and removing the coordinates of the previous cities. But when the last city on the arrayList happens to be the previous city, it gets removed but everything stops.

Here is the link to the code :

https://codeshare.io/5e6xB9

How do I fix this problem? Should I use a linked list instead of an arrayList?

Your help will be much appreciated

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem is with `.remove(i)` lines. It removes element from list and moves remaining elements to the left.

But at first glance you have too much overhead in your code. Lists, arrays, Stacks, twice file read, twice parse array... You need review your code, and at least I'd suggest make class City with x and y coordinates.